# JavaScript scope, break for cycle from function callback

Tags: javascript, scope, cycle

I need to break cycle if proccess = true, but it's undefined.

```
        var mapFound;
        var locations = {$addressTest};
        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; ++i) {
            getCoordinates(
                    locations[i],
                    function(proccess) {
                    }
            )
            if(proccess) { break; }
        }
```

Comment: The problem is that the code is asynchronous, when you use `console.log(mapFound)` the map hasn't been found yet.

Comment: Is there any other methods how to break for cycle by proccess callback?

Comment: You could place the `console.log` next to the `mapFound = process;` part. What exactly do you need?

Comment: I need to break cycle if proccess = true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be basically that `getCoordinates()` makes an asynchronous call.

By the time the loop is over you haven't received even the first response, based on your question text, so you need to use another solution.

I mean by this that you **won't** be able to *break the cycle*, because by the time the cycle is over you **still don't know** if process is true.

Depending on your implementation you might want to take a look at [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Although it might be easier to wrap the whole thing in a function that executes a callback:

```
function getCoords(locations, name, callback){
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        getCoordinates( locations[i], name,
            function(proccess) {
                if(process){
                    console.log("Map found in "+locations[i]);
                    callback.call();
                }
            }
        );
    }
}

getCoords({$addressTest}, {$name}, function(){
    // Place here whatever you want to do once the map is found.
    // you can get the map location by passing it as an argument for the callback.
});
```

Comment: Yes, getCoordinates is google api's "geocoder.geocode" method, i ll try to use your solutions, if it works i ll mark as answer.

Comment: If it doesn't work you might want to edit your answer and include the source for the `getCoordinates()` function so we can debug the whole thing.